# Is it possible to support the iPhone 6 screen, but not iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Is it possible to support the iPhone 6 screen, but not iPhone 6 Plus? I'd like the app to use the full screen resolution on the iPhone 6, but don't have the time to redesign some parts of the interface for the iPhone 6 Plus.

Can I support the iPhone 6 screen but have 6 Plus users just see a zoomed-in version of the iPhone 6 interface?

Comment: This isn't a good idea even if it's possible. You'll be providing a suboptimal experience to a large number of users. If you don't want to redesign the interface, you should at least present the same content at native resolution...

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible. The only way to indicate that your app supports iPhone 6 or 6 Plus bigger screen is to add launch XIB or storyboard file (or png launch image for iPhone 6 or 6+). Once you are done, iPhone will not zoom the screen in neither case. So if you add support for iPhone 6, you automatically add support for iPhone 6 Plus and if you do not add that support, you will get zoomed screen in both cases.

It is indicated here in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. You can still use png files for launch images on the new iPhones. The question is whether providing one for iPhone 6 and not 6+ will cause the 6+ to scale up the app...

Comment: Yes you can use png, but without launch XIB screen will be zoomed anyway

Comment: Have you tried it? ["Although it’s best to use a launch file for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, you can instead supply static launch images if necessary "](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: Yes I have. Unless you fill in this new 'Launch Screen File' input field in the Xcode, your app will not support iPhone 6/6+ full screen sizes

Comment: You can definitely use PNG's - a launch XIB is not required.

Comment: Even so, the answer to your question is no, regardless like you it or not

Answer (score 3):

No, if you add launch image for iPhone 6 then  automatically added support for iPhone 6 Plus as well. if you not add launch screen for iPhone 6 then  you will get zoomed screen in both devices(iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus). because **Apple doesn't let you limit apps to a specific model.** You can limit base on required device capabilities such as the M7 chip or a gyroscope.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Seems correct, just tested it on my project by removing the HD 5.5 launchimage (but leaving the HD 4.7 in place), still looks as if it was there

Comment: yes, @JasperPol, it will automatically support for iPhone 6 Plus. if there is only launch image of iPhone 6 device.

Answer (score 2):

Set proper Lunch Image with name and size.
following are device and it's name and size of lunch image.

- iPhone4     -> 320x480(2x) ->   640x960: Default@2x.png
- iPhone5     -> 320x568(2x) ->  640x1136: Default-568h@2x.png
- iPhone6     -> 375x667(2x) ->  750x1334: Default-667h@2x.png
- iPhone6Plus -> 414x736(3x) -> 1242x2208: Default-736h@3x.png
- iPhoneX     -> 375x812(3x) -> 1125x2436: Default-812h@3x.png